# Ubuntu Server 14.04 does not boot upon restart following fresh installation

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04 on an old system I have rebuilt (Intel Core 2 Duo with 4GB RAM, PATA HDD).  I've succeeded in installing Ubuntu using a USB stick and the system reboots to run the new installation.  However, it hangs at the point where the OS should begin to load.  I have checked that the system is trying to boot from the hard drive and not the USB stick.

If I try to replace the USB stick, the system still hangs at the same point, regardless of whether I tell the system to boot from the USB stick or the hard drive.  I can, however, boot into Ubuntu Desktop from the USB stick and reformat the drives from there.  I can then try a fresh installation but the problem reoccurs.

I'm not a complete beginner with Ubuntu and have used installations of the desktop version for several years, however I would not consider myself an expert.  This is my first attempt at using Ubuntu Server.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might try install another kernel. Sometimes additional kernel needs to be installed. You can run `Ubuntu` from USB, run a terminal, mount the system to `/mnt`, and install new kernel from here:

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
```

for example this one (when you are using AMD64):

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.10-trusty/
```

EDIT:
You need to make `sudo su -` firstly. Mount your main filesystem: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`.

You can then `chroot` to the system:

```
chroot /mnt
```

and install new kernel:

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.10-trusty/linux-headers-3.13.11-03131110-generic_3.13.11-03131110.201410302136_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.10-trusty/linux-headers-3.13.11-03131110_3.13.11-03131110.201410302136_all.deb          
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13.11.10-trusty/linux-image-3.13.11-03131110-generic_3.13.11-03131110.201410302136_amd64.deb
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: I tried this.  I couldn't work out how to get the required permissions to make chroot work.  One other thing I did try though was a clean install of 15.04.  The same problem occurred, however I did get it to work (just) if I replaced the USB stick I'd used for the installation (although it wasn't very reliable and there was no connection to my network).  If the USB stick wasn't there the installation would hang at the same point.

Comment: You need to get root, I'll make the necessary amendments to my first post.

Comment: OK, thanks for updating.  I've managed to get past the chroot stage, now I can't download anything.  It seems as if I can't connect to the internet now I've changed root.

Comment: Do you have network configured as usual?  Try that out and post us the outcome,

Comment: Thanks for helping with this.  In the end I sold out and used the desktop version of Ubuntu, which installed properly.